# Sitecore in container not accessible within Corporate VPN (Global Protect)

Tags: docker

**Outcome**

Able to run and access sitecore container within Corporate VPN network (Global Protect) so that we can rollout sitecore docker container practice for all developers.

**Problem**

We managed to get the container running with various hacks such as copying zscalar root cert and setting InterfaceMetric priority to low etc. However, I can access the sitecore only when disconnecting from VPN. As soon as I connect to VPN (Global Protect), I see this error below:

[image]

Not able to find any concrete solution at the moment. Keen to hear how you've rolled Sitecore Docker practices to your corporate network.

Comment: What worked for me, was ensuring that I was logged into Sitecore in CM, browse some URLs in CD, and browse some more URLs on whatever Rendering Host you have setup, whilst Global Protect is disconnected.
Then reconnecting to Global Protect, the connection somehow remains between the containers and everything works.
Your mileage may vary depending on your corporate VPN setup.

Comment: You (your IT team) need to update the Global Protect settings. This is not something you are going to solve otherwise.

Comment: See also https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-problem-on-windows-with-globalprotect-vpn/54259

Comment: Are you routing all your traffic through the VPN or is it a split tunnel? If you are on a split tunnel then you(/IT) could route the .local traffic away from the VPN. A tool like proxifer gives lots of flexibility around this but it would be best to talk to the team that administer the Global Protect VPN.

Comment: How do we find out whether its doing split or not?